Unable to import local JS file into Observable Framework
I am trying to include some React components I created into Observable Framwork. The observable markdown file is in my_project/docs/ directory. The JS files defining the react component are in my_project/docs/components. You can see how I am trying to include it. I am getting a strange error when I do this (pasted at the very end)
First the files.
Markdown file:
(./docs/test.md)
https://gist.github.com/why-not/87e776434cb889631f6739e124d00feb
Component file
(./docs/components/MyComponent.js)
import React from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, Observable!</h1>
      <p>This is a React component embedded in Observable Markdown.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;

Finally
Component file
(./docs/components/renderComponent.js)
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

export function renderMyComponent(container) {
  ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, container);
}

Note all I am trying to do is to import to see if it works. I am not trying to do anything else.
I get this error on the server console.
GET /_import/components/renderComponent.js?sha=e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
GET /_observablehq/stdlib/inputs.css
GET /_npm/isoformat@0.2.1/_esm.js
GET /_npm/canvas-confetti@1.9.3/_esm.js
GET /_observablehq/stdlib/inputs.js
GET /_npm/htl@0.3.1/_esm.js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:18)
    at pp$4.raise (file:///Users/senthil/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Parent/workspace/test_observable/quicktest/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.mjs:3567:13)
    at pp$9.unexpected (file:///Users/senthil/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Parent/workspace/test_observable/quicktest/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.mjs:766:8)
    at pp$5.parseExprAtomDefault (file:///Users/senthil/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Parent/workspace/test_observable/quicktest/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.mjs:2930:8)
    at pp$5.parseExprAtom (file:///Users/senthil/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Parent/workspace/test_observable/quicktest/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.mjs:2925:17)
    at pp$5.parseExprSubscripts (file:///Users/senthil/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Parent/workspace/test_observable/quicktest/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.mjs:2709:19)
    at pp$5.parseMaybeUnary (file:///Users/senthil/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Parent/workspace/test_observable/quicktest/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.mjs:2675:17)
    at pp$5.parseExprOps (file:///Users/senthil/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Parent/workspace/test_observable/quicktest/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.mjs:2602:19)
    at pp$5.parseMaybeConditional (file:///Users/senthil/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Parent/workspace/test_observable/quicktest/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.mjs:2585:19)
    at pp$5.parseMaybeAssign (file:///Users/senthil/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Parent/workspace/test_observable/quicktest/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.mjs:2552:19)
    at pp$5.parseExprList (file:///Users/senthil/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Parent/workspace/test_observable/quicktest/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.mjs:3438:18) {
  pos: 168,
  loc: Position { line: 6, column: 18 },
  raisedAt: 169
}


I am new to JS/React/Observable. Any help is much appreciated. Also if this doesn't seem workable, if you can point to any working sample that imports a local JS file in Observable Framework is appreciated.

Since Observable Framework ^1.9.0, it now supports React JSX files. Please take a look at the documentation here.
To get your example working, I would rename your MyComponent.js file to a .jsx file, and then, in your markdown file, you simply have:

```js
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.js";
```

```jsx
display(<MyComponent />);
```

Note that, if you need to import React and useEffect etc. in your component file, you could use the dynamic import format:

```js
import React, {useState, useRef} from "npm:react";
```



